# custom memory allocator - segfault

Tags: linux, pointers, debugging, memory, memory-management

me and my friend are trying to develop custom memory allocator in linux ubuntu 16.04.
We got stuck because of an error, btw its our first time 
that we are trying to code something like that so we are not the best debuggers the error is :  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
and here is the code.
can anybody help us understand whats wrong ? 
Thank you!

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

struct header_t {   
size_t size;
unsigned is_free;
struct header_t *next; };

struct header_t *head = NULL, *tail = NULL; 
pthread_mutex_t global_malloc_lock;

struct header_t *get_free_block(size_t size)
 {  
struct header_t *curr = head;   
while(curr) {   
/* see if there's a free block that can accomodate requested size */        
if (curr->is_free && curr->size >= size)
        return curr;
    curr = curr->next; 
}   
return NULL; 
}

void free(void *block) 
{   
struct header_t *header, *tmp;
/* program break is the end of the 
process's data segment */   
void *programbreak;

if (!block)         
return;
pthread_mutex_lock(&global_malloc_lock);
header = (struct header_t*)block - 1;

/* sbrk(0) gives the current program break address */


programbreak = sbrk(0);

/*
   Check if the block to be freed is the last one in the
   linked list. If it is, then we could shrink the size of the
   heap and release memory to OS. Else, we will keep the block
   but mark it as free.      */ 

if ((char*)block + header->size == programbreak) { 
    if (head == tail) { 
        head = tail = NULL;
       } else { 
        tmp = head;             
           while (tmp) {
            if(tmp->next == tail) {
                tmp->next = NULL;
                tail = tmp;
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }       
/* sbrk() with a negative argument decrements the program break.
       So memory is released by the program to OS.      */


    sbrk(0 - header->size - sizeof(struct header_t)); 


    /* Note: This lock does not really assure thread
       safety, because sbrk() itself is not really
       thread safe. Suppose there occurs a foregin sbrk(N)
       after we find the program break and before we decrement
       it, then we end up realeasing the memory obtained by
       the foreign sbrk().      */      

pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_malloc_lock);
    return;
}
header->is_free = 1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_malloc_lock);
}

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    size_t total_size;
    void *block;
    struct header_t *header;
    if (!size)
        return NULL;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&global_malloc_lock);
    header = get_free_block(size);
    if (header) {
        /* Woah, found a free block to accomodate requested memory. */
        header->is_free = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_malloc_lock);
        return (void*)(header + 1); 
    } 
    /* We need to get memory to fit in the requested block and header 
from OS. */
    total_size = sizeof(struct header_t) + size;
    block = sbrk(total_size);
    if (block == (void*) -1) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_malloc_lock);
    return NULL;
}
header = block;
header->size = size;
header->is_free = 0;
header->next = NULL;
if (!head)
    head = header;
if (tail)
    tail->next = header;
tail = header;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_malloc_lock);
return (void*)(header + 1);
}

void *calloc(size_t num, size_t nsize)
{
size_t size;
void *block;
if (!num || !nsize)
    return NULL;
size = num * nsize;
/* check mul overflow */
if (nsize != size / num)
    return NULL;
block = malloc(size);
if (!block)
    return NULL;
memset(block, 0, size);
return block;
}


void *realloc(void *block, size_t size)
 {
struct header_t *header;
void *ret;
if (!block || !size)
    return malloc(size);
header = (struct header_t*)block - 1;
if (header->size >= size)
    return block;
ret = malloc(size);
if (ret) {
    /* Relocate contents to the new bigger block */
    memcpy(ret, block, header->size);
    /* Free the old memory block */
    free(block);
  }
  return ret;
 }
```

Comment: provide the `main()` function to know how you are calling.

Comment: Do you have some unit tests?  Unit tests are a critical part of modern software development, and can provide any code with an easy way to verify it works correctly.

Comment: I solved the error by adding the functions prototype before the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because the functions were not prototyped [decalred].
Once I added functions prototype. The code worked.

For more information about prototyping: http://www.trytoprogram.com/c-programming/function-prototype-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

**mutex variable** should be **initialized** before using it for applying lock. your `global_malloc_lock` is not initialized.

you can't initialize `mutex` variable as of `normal variable`.

```
pthread_mutex_t global_malloc_lock = 0 ;// invalid .. you may thinking since it's it declared as global it's initialized with 0 which is wrong
```

Initialize the mutex variable by calling `pthread_mutex_init()` or using `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER ;`

for your code add this

```
pthread_mutex_t global_malloc_lock = pthread_mutex_t global_malloc_lock;
```